# How to solve step No.6? contain nullvalue for step 6....... why does step 6 contain empty value(Nullexception)?

Tags: c#, roslyn

```cs
namespace consoleApp6 {
    public class Person {
        public int Add() {
            return 400;
        }
        static void main() {
            string solutionPath = @"C:\Users\sslindia\source\repos\ConsoleApp6\ConsoleApp6.sln";
            var msWorkspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
            var solution = msWorkspace.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionPath).Result;
            var methodProjectComp = solution.Projects.Single(x = >x.Name == "ConsoleApp6").GetCompilationAsync().Result;
            var classWithMethodToSearchFor = methodProjectComp.GetTypeByMetadataName("ConsoleApp6.Person");
            var methodToSearchFor = classWithMethodToSearchFor.GetMembers("Add").First() as IMethodSymbol; //why this step contain empty value(Nullexception)
            //Nullexception for above step(MethodTosearchFor)
            var references = SymbolFinder.FindReferencesAsync(methodToSearchFor, solution).Result;
            var callers = SymbolFinder.FindCallersAsync(methodToSearchFor, solution).Result;
            int c = references.Select(x = >x.Locations.Count()).Sum();
            Console.WriteLine(c);
        }
    }
}
```

This is a Roslyn project using symbolfinder class. How to get references to a method using symbolfinder class?